# Under what circumstances can I draw a rectangle inside a rectangle under the following circumstances.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

If we are given four positive numbers $a,b,c,d$, can we draw a rectangle with the sides $c,d$ inside the rectangle with sides $a,b$ but so that the sides aren't parallel?

Comment: If $a>c$ and $b>d$, you can draw it so that the sides _are_ parallel, and then you have room to turn the inner rectangle a fraction a degree. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The point is that the rectangles aren't parallel, so the smaller is touching the sides of the bigger one.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on $a,b,c,d$, right. If $a = b = 2000$ and $c=d=1$, this is clearly possible. But if $a = b = c = d$, then this is no longer possible because at least two of the edges of the inner rectangle would cross the edges of the outer one.